# How do I use Field Selection to return a contained field with the Mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

I am storing Tweets in a MongoDB database, and would like to use Field Selectors (http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection) to return just the text, the date and the screen name of the user.

```
{ 
    "_id" : NumberLong("213686009408"), 
    "text" : "RT @Milanello: Lightning over the Donb...", 
    "created_at" : "Fri, 15 Jun 2012 17:37:38 +0000", 
    "user" : { 
        "screen_name" : "xxxxx", 
        "profile_image_url" : "http://a0.twimg.com/pro[...].jpg"
    }
}
```

Creating a query that returns just the text and date is easy enough:

```
> db.abc.find({},{created_at:1,text:1})
```

I'm not sure how to return the user.screen_name property as well?

[UPDATE]

I had previously tried using the dot notation and it threw an exception, however, as per both answers below (I have +1'd both) the dot notation does work, but only if you use "" around the attribute names.

So, this does NOT work:

```
db.abc.find({},{created_at:1,text:1, user.screen_name:1})
```

But this DOES:

```
db.abc.find({},{created_at:1,text:1, "user.screen_name":1})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dot notation](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29) as you would in a query:

```
db.abc.find({},{created_at:1,text:1, "user.screen_name" : 1})
```

However, the field will not be flattened, so the result objects still have a `user`-subdocument:

```
{ "_id" : NumberLong("4546545"), 
  "created_at" : "Fri, 15 Jun...", 
  "user" : { "screen_name" : "John Doe" } 
}
```

However, flattening this in code shouldn't be a big problem.

Comment: Thanks - I had used:
> db.abc.find({},{created_at:1,text:1, user.screen_name : 1})

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dot notation to query for values within the array. I created a similar document, modified the _id field, and ran the following queries successfully -

```
> db.abc.find({},{'user.screen_name': 1})
{ "_id" : 1200, "user" : { "screen_name" : "xxxxx" } }

> db.abc.find({'user.screen_name': "xxxxx"})
{ "_id" : 1200, "text" : "RT @Milanello: Lightning over the Donb...", "created_at" : "Fri, 15 Jun 2012 17:37:38 +0000", "user" : { "screen_name" : "xxxxx", "profile_image_url" : "http://a0.twimg.com/pro[...].jpg" } }
```

There's more infomation on advanced queries [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries).

Update: Looks like I posted this 2 minutes after mnemosyn so accept his answer first.